# Sort in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I do not know how to do the sort with ArrayList, I have the sample codes of sorting date in a medical history arraylist:

```
  ........
  private List<MedicalHistory> sortByDate(List<MedicalHistory> data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < data.size(); j++) {
            if (data.get(i).getDate().compareTo(data.get(j).getDate()) > 0) {
                MedicalHistory m = data.get(j);
                data.set(j , data.get(i));
                data.set(i, m);
               .......
```

So first of all, I do not know what does j mean, secondly,what do the last data.set stand for? Could anyone explain its logic flow? Thank you!

Comment: You have Arrays.sort(variable here) method or use a comparator for custom objects

Comment: Looks like a slightly dodgy bubble sort, which has average-case quadratic complexity (i.e. it's not very good). The last `data.set` sets the i'th item to the previous value of the j'th item (before you overwrote it). See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> what does j mean

`j` is an iterator - it helps you "know" which element is being
   processed at the moment.

> what do the last data.set stand for?

The `data.set()` is setting new value to the `data` ArrayList, in the specific location - so it will hold the information according to the sort order.

The 3 lines:

```
    MedicalHistory m = data.get(j);
    data.set(j , data.get(i));
    data.set(i, m);
```

is basically swapping the data in the ArrayList in the index `i` with the data in index `j`.

---

As a side note, you can use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you amit, does it have same concept with sorting in Array?

Comment: @peiwang yes, sorting array can be done in a very similar way as well. Note that this sort however is not very efficient, there are better sorting algorithms, such as [Quick Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Comment: so if I sort array or arraylist , better use array.sort()and collections.sort(),right?

Comment: Arrays.sort() and Collections.sort(), and yes. Make sure your objects are [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) - or send a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to the `sort()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Collections.sort(data) for sorting..

Comment: This is not answering the question.